# How to solve $3^{\sqrt{\log_{3}{x}}}+x^{\sqrt{\log_{3}{x}}}=6$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How can i solve the following equation?
$$
3^{\sqrt{\log_{3}{x}}}+x^{\sqrt{\log_{3}{x}}}=6
$$
It is clear that $x=3$ is a solution of this equation. But how can i prove that there is another solution or not?

Comment: Do you means $\log_3 x$?

Comment: @EmilioNovatiYes.

Comment: What's your thought here?  Is the left-hand-side always increasing?  Have you tried graphing this??

Comment: @Gaffney i have no idea about the graph of this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $t=\sqrt{\log_3x}$, so $\log_3x=t^2$ and $x=3^{t^2}$. Thus the equation becomes
$$
3^t+(3^{t^2})^t=6
$$
that is,
$$
3^t+3^{t^3}=6
$$
Note that the initial condition says $t\ge0$. The function
$$
f(t)=3^t+3^{t^3}
$$
defined over $[0,\infty)$ is clearly increasing.

Answer (score 3):

$3^{\sqrt{\log_{3}x}}+x^{\sqrt{\log_{3}x}}$ can be rewritten as $e^{\frac{\log^\frac{3}{2}x}{\sqrt{\log3}}}+e^{\sqrt{\log3\cdot \log x}}$.
This is monotonically increasing when $x>0$, so it can only have one intersection with $y=6$. Therefore $x=3$ is the only solution.